# Flow of HTTP request and response with Apache tomcat and spring framework for an application

Tags: java

I am running web application in an Apache tomcat with spring. I have done `Jmeter` test with stress test but heap is getting filled faster and its not being garbage collected. When i analyzed heap dump the memory leak suspect was due to `TaskQueue` but in our code we are not doing any thing with the Task.
My question is, during process of request and response to the server with above configuration uses any task related classes. Memory leak suspects is as below

```
One instance of "java.util.TaskQueue" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 680,207,896 (82.39%) bytes. The instance is referenced by org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread @ 0xc1b52018 ajp-bio-8009-exec-243 , loaded by "java.net.URLClassLoader @ 0xce67a9b8". The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.TimerTask[]" loaded by "<system class loader>"
```

Comment: Too much requests were in queue due to not enough throughput of application.
That could be the reason of why GC does not work at all. Abjust the number of request (or size) in stress test.

Comment: Hi bro Thanks, i reduced the number of hits using jmeter, But even though memory is at 600 MB level which has reduced from 800 MB or so, Still I want it to be clear at certain level.

Comment: Could you upload the system metric graph by jmeter? And what happend you forcely trigger GC?

Comment: I am using java VisualVM tool to track heap memory usage ,there we have option to do gc but memory is not being cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to look in to code for memory leaks.In my case, Some DAO class was not made as singleton and in that class constructor, we were initializing database connections again and again when ever we made jmeter stress hits.So memory occupied was very large.I resolved this issue by making that DAO class as singleton.